# Installing Kali Linux on Hp Omen 15

Tags: kali-linux, system-installation, tty, desktop-environment

I have been trying to install Kali Linux Rolling amd64 on HP Omen 15 without success. First, neither the WIFI nor the desktop were working, and a lot of googling turned out useless. Then I got the WIFI working, but the desktop was not being displayed. I can switch to the `tty` terminals, however, but I must do this early or the OS will freeze. I tried a lot, and I mean A LOT, of solutions and googling and nothing worked. I tried solutions on DebianOn, but since they don't have manuals for Omen I tried other related hardware configurations, nothing of which worked. The main problem is: how do I get that desktop display?

I also put all the pictures here:
[image: First Errors]

The ACPI errors show first, then it takes around 5 seconds for the nouveau errors to display.

[image: Second Set of errors]
These are the following errors. Takes them about 5 seconds too.

[image: Third Set of Errors]

[image: Final Set of Errors]
And these are the final errors. If these show up before I switch to a `tty`, the system freezes and I can't do anything except a hard shutdown. If I switch to a `tty` before I get these errors, I can work normally on every `tty` but the desktop display is frozen.

Edit: I also can't reboot or poweroff from the `tty`, I must hard shutdown.

Edit2: It also seems that I have only one shot at the system after installing it; I mean, I can only boot into it once - without graphics, just `ttys` - without it freezing. Every boot other than the first just freezes while booting. Even `ttys` can't work then. Also, on every non-first boot, I get a message like `BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 23s!`. This is the only message that keeps showing up after the system freezes.

Comment: @dsstorefile1 Can you please elaborate?

Comment: https://docs.kali.org/general-use/install-nvidia-drivers-on-kali-linux

Comment: [Important information regarding Kali & Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me/400065)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question, it seemed like the machine can never support the operating system, due to it being a hardware problem, a problem with the image itself, or both, but it still seemed like this operating system will never find its place on the machine. This just wasn't true!

First off, I mentioned that the WIFI was not working. So I downloaded the `iwlwifi` deb package so that I can use the WIFI normally. But remember from Edit2 of the question that I only had one chance of doing everything on the system: The system only boots normally - still without graphics - for only one time, then it freezes on every other boot. So I had to download the package and add it to my `firmware` folder on the live USB stick, and reinstall the system altogether. This solved the WIFI problem.

I wouldn't lie and say I knew this all by myself, the Kali Linux installation issued that this firmware and others were missing, and I first thought this was normal and that I can solve it once the system boots, but I was wrong.

The graphics problem remained. A full system upgrade wouldn't fix it. Installing a second desktop wouldn't fix it. Installing the NVIDIA necessary packages wouldn't fix it. And not only that, it seemed the CPU was failing and the ACPI was failing. And every time I fail - or may I say, get closer to success - I had to reinstall the system.

Then I decided to check out on that CPU stuck message, and some googling led to two ways: One, there is a problem with the laptop charger. Two, there is a line that needs to be changed in `/etc/default/grub`. Taking the second route was the ultimate success. I had to change the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet nomodeset"
```

or at least

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
```

Instead of reinstalling the system and trying this out, since I was doubtful this would work and I would have wasted more time, I tried doing this from the live USB. It too wouldn't show the desktop, so I tried appending `nomodeset` to the first boot entery of it too, and surprisingly, it worked. I again googled about updating grub from a live USB, found some useful posts, and completed the mission. I booted back to my main system, and it worked.

NOTE: Aside from telling the whole story just for the sake of telling it, I also told all the possible solutions - or are they? - that may work with anyone trying to install Kali on HP Omen, or the newer HPs in general. This message was sent from Kali Linux, in the first moments I am using it again, this time on HP Omen. When it seems all hope is lost, it just seems so.

Note2: The graphics aren't the best, but try not to install NVIDIA drivers because they cause problems.